# VBA - Multiple FOR Loops with different IF statements. Is there a way to reuse the same THEN commands instead of rewriting them in each section?

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a lengthy VBA script that has multiple for loops. Each Loop has an IF statement to check specific criteria. the THEN section contains 30 blocks of cut and paste commands to grab data from 1 sheet and arrange it into a different sheet.  After that, it writes in a new header row and moves on to the next For loop and IF with different criteria.  Instead of having the 30 blocks of THEN code in there again in each loop, is there a way I can CALL it from somewhere else?

I've already tried making a new sub and doing

```
For i = 2 To a  
  If Worksheets("Original Data").Cells(i, 1) <> "" THEN

CALL copyPaste
```

but it didn't work.

```
For i = 2 To a  
  If Worksheets("Original Data").Cells(i, 1) <> "" THEN

Worksheets("sheet1").Activate
    Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, X).Copy
    Worksheets("sheet2").Activate
    Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select  
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    b = b + 1
  End If
Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False

'code to insert New Header Row
```

(a = row count.)
(b is just another iterator because sheet 1 starts at row 2, but sheet 2 starts at row 4)

There are about 30 blocks like this for different copy paste commands. I'd rather not have the same 30 blocks appear 5+ times in the script if I can avoid it.

Comment: You're only showing snippets of code, so it's difficult  to know that you're doing, or what you tried with a separate sub. BTW your 5 lines of copy paste all reduce to the single line `Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, X).Copy  Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 1)` with no activate/select required.

Comment: Thank you, Tim.  That shortens it up quite a bit!  I was looking to reuse the same THEN commands in multiple IFs without rewriting it / having it appear multiple times. This is still an improvement though - having 30 lines in each THEN section is way better than it was before.

Comment: You could do a single loop with a select case, and then another procedure which requires parameters if all the copy/paste/arrange works the same way, so you only need to give the procedure what you want to copy in which way.